# Bash shell, trying to create and evaluate a mask

Tags: bash, shell, bit-manipulation, mask, bitmask

I'm trying to create a mask and use the bitwise operator "&" to compare to another variable and see the output. Let there be code:

```
mask=00000
mesk=00010
mosk=$mask&$mesk
echo $mosk
echo meec
```

I'm trying to expand this functionality to be able to have more characters (different error/success codes), but those lines just don't work: Executing the script will print an empty line, then "meec".

I came from an object oriented programming background, and although I've read through several documents on this subject, it seems there's something I'm missing.
Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: For  some reason, turns out the code doesn't work, it says "command 00010 not found" >_>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because usually the `&` character in the shell is the modifier to put a command in the background.

You have to use [Arithmetic Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Expansion.html) of Bash (for example) for it to work:

```
mosk=$(($mask & $mesk))
```

Comment: Darn, thanks kind stranger! I saw something about this topic but didn't manage to link both things (bit wising and aritmetic expanding).